# List of Database Naming Convention Decision Points

Tags: database, naming-conventions

I am looking to find or create a robust list of decision points for database naming conventions. I'll start with a list and ask people to suggest useful. For this exercise I do not care to indicate an preference for any particular conventions, just to create a list that any organization could use to set their standards.

In no particular order, but numbered for possible reference:

1. Use of Hungarian (prefix or suffix) for object names ("tibbling")
2. Pluralizing of tables
3. Abbreviating and standard abbreviations ("abrvtng")
4. Use or avoidance of [Escaping]
5. Indication word boundaries (pascal, camel, _, etc.)
6. Capitalization scheme
7. Key naming
8. Association/join/many-to-many table names

Answer (score 1):

There is not a general form of conventions for database objects naming but in my case and because i work on standarized framework i used somethings like this:

1. Suffix (PROCEDURE->SP, FUNCTION->FN, TRIGGER -> TRG, ETC. ), because you can see related elements easily.
2. Table names plural; field names singular
3. Generally you have a dictionary with names and abreviations.
4. N/D
5. underscore ( _ ), because many database are not case sensitive.
6. UPPERCASE
7. Primary key column sould be ID .
8. If you have TABLE named ORDERS for all orders and a TABLE of ITEMS then your "order details" table sould be called ORDERS_ITEMS

Comment: I appreciate the time to answer, but what I am looking to do is to create a list that would help frame the conversation for any organization rather than to propose the actual standard.